# Worpdress permission to edit user based on a custom profile field value

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions, user-profile

I am trying to grant permission for 'editor' role users to edit only users with a specific custom field in wordpress.

In this example the custom field is a users nationality and I have added it to user_meta like so:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="country">Country</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="country" id="country" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'country', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                <span class="description">Please enter country.</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
update_usermeta( $user_id, 'country', $_POST['country'] );
```

Basically I want to assign 1 user from each country to be able to edit only users from that same country.

I realize here that I will need to change 'input type="text"' to a fixed selection of values for `country` instead of a text input, but I wanted to see if it's even possible to restrict the permissions before fine tuning the rest of the plugin.